# Populate VIProductVersion with nsis-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, nsis

I want to use the value of the version field in my pom.xml for my nsis Windows installers. To do this I use the [nsis-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/nsis-maven-plugin/) to generate a `target/project.nsh` (which will contain an appropriate `PROJECT_VERSION` field), that then gets `!include` into my `setup.nsi`.

Here's the problem: Suppose my pom `project.version` is 1.2-SNAPSHOT. `makensis` will fail with the error:

```
[MAKENSIS] Error: invalid VIProductVersion format, should be X.X.X.X
```

So I've got two problems:

1. The "-SNAPSHOT" string

   I could chop it off before setting the `VIProductVersion` field, but then my version will appear like 1.2 when it's really not.
2. My version looks like X.X, but needs to be X.X.X.X

   Hard padding the field with two zeros (e.g. `VIProductVersion ${PROJECT_VERSION}.0.0`) will just break as soon as I change my pom `project.version` to 1.2.1

Is there a good strategy for this?

Comment: Looking at PS3MediaServer it looks like they don't even bother defining a VIProductVersion https://github.com/ps3mediaserver/ps3mediaserver/blob/384e0bb28d903dd3aa866a3828b229ccaebd41a2/src/main/external-resources/nsis/setup.nsi

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about maven but I can tell you why NSIS works like this.

You can use [`VIAddVersionKey`](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.8.3) to add any string you want (Including "ProductVersion"). `VIProductVersion` sets the [fixed (VS_FIXEDFILEINFO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646997%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) part of the win32/PE version resource, that is why it has to contain 4 16 bit numbers...

Comment: Interesting, but VIProductVersion is a required field when using VIAddVersionKey. I suppose I could set VIProductVersion to 0.0.0.0 and set the actual version with VIAddVersionKey ProductVersion "1.2-SNAPSHOT"...

Comment: The PE fixed block is required. And please don't use 0.0.0.0, use a real number because some application might want to check your version etc...

Comment: That's exactly the problem :) It is impossible to use X.X.X.X to represent 1.2-SNAPSHOT. If I were to put 1.2.0.0 in there it would be a lie. Think of the word SNAPSHOT as Alpha. How would you represent 1.2 Alpha? 1.2 Alpha != 1.2.0.0. Think of the nightmare when the non alpha version comes out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem.
Since I use the [copy-maven-problem](http://evgeny-goldin.com/wiki/Copy-maven-plugin) in my project, I also used it to precess the `project.nsh` with a Groovy snippet:

```
<resource>
    <targetPath>${project.build.directory}</targetPath>
    <file>${project.build.directory}/installer-header.nsh</file>
    <destFileName>installer-header-processed.nsh</destFileName>
    <!-- groovy extension point -->
    <process>{{ 
            def versionsList = project.version.replaceFirst("-SNAPSHOT", "").tokenize('.')
            while(!(versionsList.size >= 4)){
                versionsList.add('0')
            }
            files[0].append("!define VI_PRODUCT_VERSION \"" + versionsList.join('.') + "\"\n")
        }}</process>
</resource>
<resource>
    <targetPath>${project.build.directory}</targetPath>
    <file>${project.build.directory}/installer-header-processed.nsh</file>
    <destFileName>installer-header.nsh</destFileName>
    <move>true</move>
</resource>
```

Check the doc to this plugin and adapt the variable/file names (i.e. I call the header file `installer-header.nsh`)

After this, you have a variable `VI_PRODUCT_VERSION` (rename as you want) in the header which you can use in your `setup.nsi`.

I know this looks like q bad hack, but it works for now. I hope that there will be plugin-generated variables in the future..

PS: Call the copy-maven-plugin BEFORE nsis-maven-plugin within the packaging phase for it to work. I defined the copy plugin before the nsis plugin - the `.nsh` is generated within the prepare-package phase, so it exists before the processing.

Comment: This snippet does not check whether the project.version has a 5th version element.